# update DOM only after submit form vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have a form with two checkboxes. each of them are related to an object to change its props 'is_active' on true or false. on click, DOM updates immediatly : if checked, object appears and if not, disappears. on submit, object is persisted in database.

```html
<form @submit.prevent="submit()">
    <div v-for="(checker_website, index) in website.checkers" :key="index">
        <input type="checkbox" class="mr-2" :id="index" :true-value="1" :false-value="0" v-model="website.checkers[index].is_active">
        <label :for="index">{{checker_website.checker.name}}</label>
    </div>

    <div class="text-right mt-5">
         <button class="save flex font-semibold py-2 px-4 rounded">Enregistrer</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
submit() {
    axios.post('/app/store',{websites: this.websites})
},
```

also, I have a {{total}} prop which is updated after any change on checkbox. it is calculated this way :

```js
computed: {
    total() {
        let total = 0;
        this.websites.forEach(website => {
            website.checkers.forEach(checker => {
                if (checker.is_active === 1 && checker.checker.status === 1) {
                    total += checker.checker.price
                }
            })
        })
        return total
    }
},
```

and displayed like this :

```html
<span class="p-6">
    Total mensuel : {{total}}€/HT
    </span>
```

what I want is to update DOM right after the submit and I find no way to do that. any help will be very appreciated !

Comment: Tried this one? https://vuejs.org/api/component-instance.html#nexttick

Comment: What DOM isn't updating? `{{ total }}`? I don't see that used anywhere.

Comment: @tony19 DOM is updating reactively  and that is my problem. I want DOM to be updated after the submit. {{total}} is updated reactively too (I will edit my post to be more explicit)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to convert the `total` computed prop into a data property that gets updated on submit:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      total: 0,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    // total() {⋯} // now a data property
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      this.total = this.getTotal()
    },
    getTotal() {
      let total = 0
      this.websites.forEach(website => {
        website.checkers.forEach(checker => {
          if (checker.is_active === 1 && checker.checker.status === 1) {
            total += checker.checker.price
          }
        })
      })
      return total
    },
  },
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-update-total-on-submit?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)

Comment: thank you for your answer. it works but when I first arrive on the page {{total}} = 0 even if checkboxes are checked. moreover, I don't understand the function you put in computed props.

Comment: The commented out function in `computed` is meant to tell you to remove the `total` computed prop, and make it a data property.

Comment: The `total` would be `0` initially because it's only called on submit. That's the whole premise of the answer. If you need it to be called when you mount the component, I'm assuming the data comes in as a prop, and you should call `getTotal` on mount. Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: I found another way to perform the trick. I let total into computed method and set a watch on my data